# Does go modules support upgrading transitive dependencies?

Tags: go, go-modules

Say I have a go module with each dependency pointing to different versions of the same transitive dependency.

```
example.com/foo v1.1 --> example3.com/baz v0.1
example2.com/bar v2.1 --> example3.com/baz v0.2
```

Say I find a bug in `v0.2`, which is the version resolved by the `go modules` [minimum version algorithm](https://golang.org/ref/mod#minimal-version-selection), and would like to upgrade all dependencies that point to a specified version of a transitive dependency. Let's call it `example3.com/v0.4`.

Is there a command that I can run that upgrades `example.com/foo` and `example2.com/bar` so that the transitive dependencies are satisfied by `example3.com/v0.4` if they exist?

Ideally I would call `go get <some flag> example3.com/bar v0.4` and the result would look something like:

```
example.com/foo v1.x --> example3.com/baz v0.4
example2.com/bar v2.x --> example3.com/baz v0.4
```

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-file-require ?

Comment: I think it should. Have you tried `go mod tidy`

Comment: If I run `go get -u example3.com/baz@v0.4` followed by `go mod tidy` I get an indirect reference (on `go 1.16`) in my mod file. But, the modules that depend on this new version remain at their same version. I want `go mod` to resolve the upgrade and change the `go.mod` file to reflect new versions.

Comment: have you tried both require and replace ? https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace

Comment: Yes. require and replace both are useful in that they allow upgrading the specific version of that transitive dependency, but they have no effect on versions of the top level dependencies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go's dependencies only specific minimum versions — they don't pin exact or maximum versions, and do assume that dependencies generally remain compatible as they evolve. So `go get example3.com/bar@v0.4` will *upgrade* `example3.com/bar` to `v0.4`, and will *downgrade* anything that depends on a version *higher than* `v0.4`, but it will assume that anything written against `v0.1` or `v0.2` is more-or-less compatible — and you could perhaps verify that using `go test all`.

So there isn't a built-in command that directly does what you're trying to do.

---

That said, you could use [go mod graph](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-graph) and `grep` to figure out which external modules depend on *any* `example3.com/bar`. Then you could use `sed` to chop those lines down to just the module path, and upgrade those modules using `go get`:

```
MODS=$(go mod graph | grep '@.* example3.com/bar@.*' | sed 's/@.*//')
go get -d $MODS
```

---

You *could* do that even more precisely using `go list -json all`, which would give you structured information about the *packages* imported by the main module. The `Deps`, `ImportPath`, and `Module` fields are probably sufficient to identify which packages need to be updated. (There may be an elegant way to filter and transform that using `jq`, but I don't have the bandwidth to figure that out today.)